# Force scroll to top updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrolltop

I am trying to force my page to load always on the top. I don't know if I have to define on-refresh or on-load but I've tried everything. I've searched all the previous questions and non of them seemed to work for me. I checked in Chrome and Mozilla. So do you have any suggestions? What should I do?

I tried the following:

1.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```

2.

```
jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0},0);
```

3.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
  $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```

4.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.hash) { 
        //bind to scroll function
        $(document).scroll( function() {
            var hash = window.location.hash
            var hashName = hash.substring(1, hash.length);
            var element;

            //if element has this id then scroll to it
            if ($(hash).length != 0) {
                element = $(hash);
            }
            //catch cases of links that use anchor name
            else if ($('a[name="' + hashName + '"]').length != 0)
            {
                //just use the first one in case there are multiples
                element = $('a[name="' + hashName + '"]:first');
            }

            //if we have a target then go to it
            if (element != undefined) {
                window.scrollTo(0, element.position().top);
            }
            //unbind the scroll event
            $(document).unbind("scroll");
        });
    }

});
```

5.

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 // do your js stuff
 $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```

6.

```
$("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
}, 600);
```

Comment: Try this one. `$(document).load().scrollTop(0);`

Comment: No this one was one of the first to try but it  didn't work.

Comment: Have you check in `$(document).ready(function(){` by putting anything like alert that, when load it is going into ready function?

Comment: To be honest no I haven't . What kind of alert? any code examples?

Comment: Like:  `$(document).ready(function(){
 alert("hello");
   $(window).scrollTop(0);
});`

Comment: Yes it does going into ready function. The message was cool though :)

Answer (score 0):

use `animate` function

```
$("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
}, 600);
```

Comment: thanks but no it doesn't work either (not in Mozilla or Chrome)